0-10V or 4-20mA conversion to 0-3.3V for Microcontroller ADC
I'm building an electronic project that will have hybrid analog input (can accept both 0-10V or 4-20mA).
The user can use jumpers to select the desired mode, which is either 0-10V or 4-20mA.
My microcontroller ADC accept 0-3.3V range.

To read 0-10V previously I added a simple voltage divider circuit with zener diode protection that was working fine.
To read 4-20ma I added a 150R 1% 1/4W resistor with zener diode protection circuit.
But the end user is facing some kind of error and accuracy issue.

Existing circuit:

So I was considering replacing the above circuit with a rail-to-rail opamp. for proper impedance matching and a stable output from 0-3.3V range.
Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated
Regards

"Also input & output impedace issue persists." what does that mean? And: how are you planning to connect your opamp? You can't just "replace" something with an opamp; you might with an op-amp circuit, yet it's not clear to me what the motivation there would be.

and: "But the end user is facing some kind of error and accuracy issue." can you please be a bit more precise than that?

Technically, you are converting 0 - 10 V or 0 - 20 mA. The scaling and offset for 4 - 20 mA will, I presume, be handled in software.

@MarcusMüller may be my question is bit confusing. My motive of using opamp was,  it offers high input impedance so they won't load the signal source (preventing signal distortion) and can drive the ADC input efficiently for it's low o/p impedance.

but what sense does that make? The point of a 4-20 mA loop is that you load it.

How is the ADC reference voltage created and from where?

In general you cannot design a voltage divider so that you end up exactly in the ADC range. There must be margins, particularly if you use cheap 1% resistors and grab the ADC reference directly from the plain 3.3V supply net etc.

@Lundin The voltage divider is for external sensors (can be either 0-10V or 0-5V output).That was my old circuit to sample analog voltage input. and the voltage divider output reference is connected to a 12 bit ADC.

We don't know anything about the ADC, so it's impossible to know what to do to protect it. All we can do is make sure it never sees a voltage outside the range 0V to +3.3V. That's easy to do with an op-amp powered by 0V and +3.3V, and whose input resistance we know to be extremely high. Then it's simply a case of keeping the op-amp happy.
If the op-amp has input protection diodes, as most do, then we consult its datasheet to find out the maximum permissible input current, and stay well below that using a resistance in series with its input.
For TLC2271/2/4, has a maximum input current of 5mA as stated on page 5 of the datasheet, in the table "Absolute Maximum Ratings". We could aim to limit current to, say, 1mA.
It won't behave well with input voltages above \$V_{DD}-1V=+2.3V\$, so we should also keep its inputs under that. Since the op-amp won't output all the way to 0V or +3.3V, I suggest limiting that range to between +0.1V and +3.2V, which you will compensate for in software.
If we constrain inputs to the range \$0 < V_{IN} < +1.5\$, gain should be:
$$ A = \frac{3.2 - 0.1}{1.5 - 0} = 2.07 $$
For a 0V to 10V source signal, the potential divider must attenuate by a factor of:
$$ B = \frac{1.5 - 0}{10 - 0} = 0.15 $$
An input of 0V should produce an output of +0.1V, which means we need to apply an offset to the input. It's not advisable to derive this offset directly from the +3.3V supply, since doing so will inject any supply noise into the signal. The recommended way would be to use a precision reference such as the TL431, to obtain a fixed, stable voltage, and use that instead:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Note that if you have several channels of input to process, this same reference voltage of +2.50V can be used for all of them, so you build this reference (TL431 and R1) just once.
That produces a nice linear relationship between \$V_X\$ and \$V_{IN}\$, with \$+0.05V < V_X < 1.53V\$ as IN goes between \$0V < V_{IN} < 10V \$.
The 4-20mA input doesn't need an offset, since a low starts at 4mA, which will naturally incur an offset. You require 20mA to correspond to +1.5V op-amp input, so the conversion resistance is:
$$ R_C = \frac{+1.5V}{20mA} = 75\Omega $$
The final circuit will look like this:

simulate this circuit
R5 protects the op-amp from input over-current, even if the sources fall well outside their expected range. The op-amp can't produce under 0V or over +3.3V, so the ADC is safe.
This is a plot of \$V_{OUT}\$ as \$V_{IN1}\$ is swept from 0V to +10V, with switch SW1 in the shown position:

With the switch in the other position, this is \$V_{OUT}\$ as current into IN2 is swept from 0 to 20mA:


Your circuit looks promising and I'll definitely try it out. I've one question near the shunt regulator-What is the purpose of that 470K res for current limmiting or anything else?

@JohnMist R2 470kΩ is the value required to raise the divider output X by 50mV or so. Then the op-amp output goes from 100mV upwards (not zero), to stay within its limited output range. Without R2, X goes down to zero, but the op-amp cannot output $2.07 \times 0V = 0V$.

The 3.3V zener diodes are going to cause large errors near the high end of the inputs. Here is a simulation showing the nominal errors with one particular 3.3V Zener (not counting Zener tolerance, which is typically something like +/-5%).
You can see the visual curvature in output vs. %F.S. input and the violet traces show you the % FS error vs. input voltage or current, nominally more than 6% error.

Adding an op-amp somehow is not going to help much with that - you'll still need to protect most op-amps (especially RRIO types)-  just was you are currently trying to protect the ADC input.
If you edit your question to indicate how exactly your proposed circuit is constructed maybe we can make suggestions.

yes,that's why I'm planning to change the circuit,

The board will have multiple analog inputs that can be either  current or voltage input.I would appreciate any suggestion

Simplest approach is to reduce the resistor values so that you throw away a bit of the ADC range. Do you have a higher voltage rail available? (eg. 5V).

Multiple 4-20 mA or 0-10 V inputs with requirement for accuracy and proper protection sounds like the job for a PLC or a OTS DAQ system.

@SpehroPefhany No sir 3.3V is the maximum supply rail. I'm using STM32f407 series as main MCU.

@MrGerber Yes it's a kind of data acquisition system and  all of the data will be transferred to a certain domain via a 4G network.

This simple solution might work:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Your error likely comes from your diode. Zeners are a poor choice in your circuit. D1 clamps the voltage to the power rail; the STM32 can tolerate the voltage drop as this diode keeps the voltage under it's maximum absolute ratings on input pins. The reson my diode arrangement works is that my diodes are reverse-biased under normal operation - yours will conduct near the Zener knee causing non-linearity seen by the ADC input.
D2 is optional if you want to be really cheap - it serves the same purpose as D1 except for under voltages. Might not be necessary in your application but its cheap "user insurance". C1 is also optional - it provides analog filtering. But you are likely already managing that in firmware. R4 provides current limiting. This is a non-critical value, but the trade off will be degree of protection vs system performance (speed/absolute error). Higher value increases protection. Lower value increases bandwidth. R1, R2 and R3 are set to provide 0V-10V and 0mA-20mA inputs to 0V-3.33V ADC input, respectively.
You wanted 4mA-20mA input instead of 0mA-20mA as I have shown. The easiest way around that is to do the offset in firmware at the expense of resolution. If you need to use all of your precious 12-bits of raw ADC performance, with appreciable added complexity, you can correct the offset with external circuitry to restore the "lost bits".

In this design I've mapped the current-loop inputs to the analog input range 0.0 ... 3.0 V.
I chose 3.0 V as maximum to add some leeway in case I had to calibrate the inputs. The voltage followers prevent unwanted influence from the MCU.

Current Input:
\$V_{ADC,IIN} = I_{IN}*150 Ω\$
\$V_{ADC,0mA} = 0 mA * 150 Ω = 0.0 V\$
\$V_{ADC,4mA} = 4 mA * 150 Ω = 0.6 V\$
\$V_{ADC,20mA} = 20 mA * 150 Ω = 3.0 V\$

Voltage Input:
\$V_{ADC,VIN} = \frac{V_{IN} * 120 kΩ}{120 kΩ + 10 kΩ + 270 kΩ} = \frac{V_{IN} * 120 kΩ}{400 kΩ}\$
\$V_{ADC,0V} = \frac{0 V * 120 kΩ}{400 kΩ} = 0.0 V\$
\$V_{ADC,10V} = \frac{10 V * 120 kΩ}{400 kΩ} = 3.0 V\$

But why you have created a voltage divider circuit which will give around 4.28V and expect the zener to clamp it to 3.3V for voltage follower opamp.

I've added the formulas. There is no 4.28V getting clamped. The Zeners are only for safety.

I recommend to add 1 kohm resistors between the OpAmp outputs and GND. This helps the OpAmp to come down close to 0 V.

@Velvet yes you're correct I forgot to add the total resistance to the formula.Thank you
